# After disabling a user, will his/her messages in Microsoft Teams be deleted?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Our company started using Microsoft Teams couple months ago. One of my colleague left the business. What will happen if I disable/delete his AAD account? We hope the messages he sent in Teams channels can be kept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. When a user is deleted from Office 365, content the user generated such as a chat conversation remains in the team's channel and in private chats.
You can take a look at this article for detail information.
[What happens to a terminated employee and their conversation history?](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/skypehybridguy/2017/09/01/microsoft-teams-what-happens-to-a-terminated-employee-and-their-conversation-history/?from=singlemessage)

Comment: Please include all the useful information from the article *in your answer itself*.